Copy Duplicates and Move them to another sheet
Dataset
Here's another post that is the same situation: Link to the post
I'm trying to find a script that goes through column A which is a concat formula of columns 1-5.
Then I want it to identify which are duplicates and copies the whole row into another worksheet.
I've modified the code within that post as it's pretty much what I'm looking for but it crashes my whole excel. I have about 80,000 lines of data which is the problem and so far my excel sheets are all formula based so it takes forever to load and I'm trying to use less formulas and more automation.
Thank you!
Tried the code within the post which works but freezes entire excel and all Microsoft applications.

Are you looking for OfficeScripts or VBA code? btw, VBA works well for 80,000 lines of data if the correct approach is used. eg. loading data into array.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

@taller Hi Taller, thanks for the solution - I've learned a lot. However, I'm running into an error that says Line 16: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') whenever I use my dataset. If I use the sample dataset everything works fine though.

Add console.log(dupVals) to check the return value.

@taller When I use the sample data set, the log returns an array. However, when I use my dataset it's not returning anything it's just [] with the same error.

Is there possible share part of your dataset w/o privacy leaking? eg. replace the sensitive data with dummy data. It's better to keep the same layout.

@taller Ah, I figured out why it's not returning the duplicates or an empty array. I have 2 ID Columns that are unique to each row. By any chance, is there a way to modify the script to select certain columns to Concat. For example, if I had 6 Columns - I want to concat Columns, A,B,D,F to find the duplicates then return all of the duplicates and all of the corresponding columns  (A,B,C,D,E,F) into the new worksheet?

What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?

Let me know when it's posted.

@taller I've created a new post. Thank you!


You don't need a helper column with Concat formula. It can be done with code (VBA or OfficeScript)

function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    const Sheet1 = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");  // modify as needed
    const Sheet2 = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet2");
    const dataRng = Sheet1.getRange("A1").getSurroundingRegion()
    // console.log(dataRng.getAddress())
    const dataVals = dataRng.getValues();
    // console.log(dataVals)
    // Merge rows into strings (same as Concat formula)
    const mergedRows: string[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < dataVals.length; i++) {
        mergedRows.push(dataVals[i].join("|"));
    }
    // console.log(mergedRows)
    const dupVals = findDuplicateRows(mergedRows);
    const rowCnt = dupVals.length;
    const colCnt = dupVals[0].length;
    // clear the output sheet
    Sheet2.getRange().clear(ExcelScript.ClearApplyTo.all);
    // write dup. rows to sheet
    Sheet2.getRange("A1").getAbsoluteResizedRange(rowCnt, colCnt).setValues(dupVals);
}

function findDuplicateRows(mergedRows: string[]): string[][] {
    const duplicateRows: string[][] = [];
    const foundRows: Set<string> = new Set();
    for (let i = 0; i < mergedRows.length; i++) {
        const row = mergedRows[i];
        if (!foundRows.has(row)) {
            for (let j = i + 1; j < mergedRows.length; j++) {
                if (row === mergedRows[j]) {
                    duplicateRows.push(row.split("|")); 
                    foundRows.add(row);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return duplicateRows;
}


